# python opencv bitwise_xor

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to combine two pictures which are segments from an original one. here is an example of two segments:

**pic a**
[image]

**pic b**
[image]

but when trying to combine them :

```
img_to_assemble = cv2.bitwise_xor(pic_a,pic_b)
```

I get the following error:

> The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same
>   size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in
>   function binary_op

Comment: You need to create a mask for one of the images and then apply `cv2.bitwise_xor`

Comment: check out [THIS LINK](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to perform what you intend to, first ensure that your images are of the same size.

And to combine the two images I performed `cv2.bitwise_or()`

Code in python:

```
img_a = cv2.imread("a.png", 1)
img_b = cv2.imread(".png", 1)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_b, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

rows,cols,channels = img_b.shape
roi = img_a[0:rows, 0:cols ]

img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_b,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask = mask_inv)
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_or(img_b, img_b, mask = mask)

dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
img_a[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst
cv2.imshow('res',img_a)
```

Here is the result I obtained as a result:

[image]